# Problem fitting when some data is missing

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, missing

I have a problem fitting a function to data, where I only have the falling and rising edges of the data, with the peak having been capped and was wondering if you have some tips.

The data should have the shape of a [Landau distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_distribution) but peak values were out of range. Example of data that I want to fit:

```
signalpart2 = {{880., 0.6299}, {880.8, 0.5354}, {881.6, 0.378}, {882.4, 0.2992}, {883.2, 0.3465}, {884., 0.4252}, {884.8, 0.4409}, {885.6, 0.3622},{886.4, 0.2992}, {887.2, 0.2362}, {888., 0.2677}, {888.8, 0.3622}, {889.6, 0.4252}, {890.4, 0.3937}, {891.2, 0.2992}, {892., 0.2362}, {892.8, 0.252}, {893.6, 0.378}, {894.4, 0.4882}, {895.2, 0.4567}, {896., 0.3622}, {896.8, 0.2677}, {897.6, 0.252}, {898.4, 0.2992}, {899.2, 0.3465}, {900., 0.3622}, {900.8, 0.2992}, {901.6, 0.2362}, {902.4, 0.2047}, {903.2, 0.2677}, {904., 0.3622}, {904.8, 0.4094}, {905.6, 0.3622}, {906.4, 0.2992}, {907.2, 0.252}, {908., 0.315}, {908.8, 0.5039}, {909.6, 0.6614}, {910.4, 0.6457}, {911.2, 0.5197}, {912., 0.4094}, {912.8, 0.5669}, {913.6, 1.3071}, {914.4, 1.9685}, {915.2, 2.}, {916., 1.6063}, {916.8, 1.0866}, {917.6, 1.1181}, {918.4, 1.8898}, {919.2, 2.}, {931.2, 2.}, {932., 1.9843}, {932.8, 1.8583}, {933.6, 1.748}, {934.4, 1.7008}, {935.2, 1.5748}, {936., 1.3858}, {936.8, 1.1654}, {937.6, 1.1496}, {938.4, 1.2598}, {939.2, 1.2756}, {940., 1.1496}, {940.8, 1.0551}, {941.6, 0.8819}, {942.4, 0.6772}, {943.2, 0.6299}, {944., 0.8346}, {944.8, 0.9449}, {945.6, 0.8189}, {946.4, 0.5827}, {947.2, 0.4252}, {948., 0.4409}, {948.8, 0.4409}, {949.6, 0.4724}, {950.4, 0.5197}, {951.2, 0.5354}, {952., 0.4724}, {952.8, 0.4252}, {953.6, 0.378}, {954.4, 0.4567}, {955.2, 0.4724}, {956., 0.4094}, {956.8, 0.378}, {957.6, 0.4409}, {958.4, 0.4882}, {959.2, 0.4882}, {960., 0.4409}, {960.8, 0.3937}, {961.6, 0.3465}, {962.4, 0.2992}, {963.2, 0.2992}, {964., 0.3465}, {964.8, 0.3465}, {965.6, 0.3622}, {966.4, 0.378}, {967.2, 0.3465}, {968., 0.315}, {968.8, 0.2677}, {969.6, 0.2677}, {970.4, 0.315}, {971.2, 0.3307}, {972., 0.3622}, {972.8, 0.378}, {973.6, 0.3465}, {974.4, 0.2677}, {975.2, 0.2047}, {976., 0.189}, {976.8,  0.2205}, {977.6, 0.252}, {978.4, 0.2677}, {979.2, 0.2677}, {980., 0.2362}, {980.8, 0.189}, {981.6, 0.1417}, {982.4, 0.1575}, {983.2, 0.2047}, {984., 0.2362}, {984.8, 0.2205}, {985.6, 0.189}, {986.4, 0.1732}, {987.2, 0.189}, {988., 0.2047}, {988.8, 0.2205}, {989.6, 0.2205}, {990.4, 0.189}, {991.2, 0.189}, {992., 0.189}, {992.8, 0.2362}, {993.6, 0.2677}, {994.4, 0.2205}, {995.2, 0.1732}, {996., 0.1575}, {996.8, 0.1575}, {997.6, 0.1732}, {998.4, 0.1732}, {999.2, 0.189}, {1000., 0.2047}, {1000.8, 0.189}, {1001.6, 0.1575}, {1002.4,0.1575}, {1003.2, 0.2047}, {1004., 0.1732}, {1004.8, 0.1575}, {1005.6, 0.1417}, {1006.4, 0.1732}, {1007.2, 0.2205}, {1008., 0.2362}, {1008.8, 0.2362}, {1009.6, 0.189}, {1010.4, 0.1102}, {1011.2, 0.0472}, {1012., 0.0472}, {1012.8, 0.0945}, {1013.6, 0.1732}, {1014.4, 0.189}, {1015.2, 0.1417}, {1016., 0.0945}, {1016.8, 0.0472}, {1017.6, 0.0472}, {1018.4, 0.0945}, {1019.2, 0.1417}, {1020., 0.2047}, {1020.8, 0.189}, {1021.6, 0.1575}, {1022.4, 0.1417}, {1023.2, 0.1417}, {1024., 0.126}, {1024.8, 0.1102}, {1025.6, 0.1102}, {1026.4, 0.1102}, {1027.2, 0.1417}, {1028., 0.1732}, {1028.8, 0.2047}, {1029.6, 0.2047}, {1030.4, 0.1575}, {1031.2, 0.1417}, {1032., 0.126}, {1032.8, 0.0787}, {1033.6, 0.0945}, {1034.4, 0.1102}, {1035.2, 0.126}, {1036., 0.126}, {1036.8,0.126}, {1037.6, 0.1102}, {1038.4, 0.0945}, {1039.2, 0.0787}, {1040., 0.1102}, {1040.8, 0.126}, {1041.6, 0.1417}, {1042.4, 0.1417}, {1043.2, 0.1417}, {1044., 0.0945}, {1044.8, 0.0472}, {1045.6, 0.}, {1046.4, 0.}, {1047.2, 0.0315}, {1048., 0.0945}, {1048.8, 0.1417}, {1049.6, 0.1417}, {1050.4, 0.1102}, {1051.2, 0.063}}
```

I've defined the function:

```
Landau[ampl_, x0_, sigma_, x_] := ampl*PDF[LandauDistribution[x0, sigma], x]
```

And I fit as follows:

```
ClearAll[ampl, x0, sigma, x];
landfit = FindFit[signalpart2[[1138 ;; 1400]],
  Landau[ampl, x0, sigma, x], {{ampl, 80}, {x0, 915}, {sigma, 8.5}}, 
  x, MaxIterations -> 20, Method -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

Which gives me the following fit:
{ampl -> 79.7375, x0 -> 911.464, sigma -> 10.5445}
[image: bad fit]

Entering the values manually gives a fit that corresponds better to how it should be (values {ampl -> 80, x0 -> 915, sigma -> 8.3} :
[image: better fit]

I've tried to limit the data that I fit to to exclude the non-zero parts before the rising edge as well as parts of the tail, which gives a slightly better fit, but still far from how it should be. Somehow it seems I need to put more weight to the higher values of the data and forcing Mathematica to not see the high values as the actual peak values.

I couldn't find any similar questions, but if I missed any I'd appreciate a link to the questions.

Thank you very much for any help and suggestions!

EDIT
The data is the voltage readout from a sensor being hit by particles and ideally a single particle should produce a Landau peak, but due to various reasons (mainly signal overlap and slow charge collection) especially the low values don't really correspond to this. The high values are more close to the Landau. It's indeed a bit arbitrary, but I will know how reliable it actually turns out to be.

This is a non-capped signal and a proper looking fit:
[image]

Which uses the following data:

```
{{840.,0.0394},{840.8,0.0787},{841.6,0.},{842.4,0.0394},{843.2,0.0394},{844.,0.},{844.8,0.0394},{845.6,0.0394},{846.4,0.0394},{847.2,0.0394},{848.,0.},{848.8,0.0394},{849.6,0.0394},{850.4,0.0394},{851.2,0.0394},{852.,0.0394},{852.8,0.},{853.6,0.},{854.4,0.0394},{855.2,0.0787},{856.,0.0394},{856.8,0.0394},{857.6,0.0394},{858.4,0.0394},{859.2,0.0394},{860.,0.0394},{860.8,0.0394},{861.6,0.0394},{862.4,0.},{863.2,0.},{864.,0.},{864.8,0.0394},{865.6,0.0394},{866.4,0.0394},{867.2,0.0394},{868.,0.0394},{868.8,0.},{869.6,0.0394},{870.4,0.0787},{871.2,0.0394},{872.,0.},{872.8,0.0394},{873.6,0.},{874.4,0.0394},{875.2,0.0787},{876.,0.0394},{876.8,0.0394},{877.6,0.0394},{878.4,0.},{879.2,0.0394},{880.,0.0394},{880.8,0.0394},{881.6,0.},{882.4,0.0394},{883.2,0.},{884.,0.0394},{884.8,0.0787},{885.6,0.0787},{886.4,0.0394},{887.2,0.},{888.,0.},{888.8,0.0394},{889.6,0.0394},{890.4,0.0394},{891.2,0.0394},{892.,0.0787},{892.8,0.},{893.6,0.},{894.4,0.0394},{895.2,0.0787},{896.,0.0394},{896.8,0.0394},{897.6,0.0394},{898.4,0.},{899.2,0.0394},{900.,0.0394},{900.8,0.0394},{901.6,0.0394},{902.4,0.0394},{903.2,0.},{904.,0.0394},{904.8,0.0394},{905.6,0.0394},{906.4,0.0787},{907.2,0.},{908.,-0.0394},{908.8,0.},{909.6,0.0394},{910.4,0.0787},{911.2,0.0787},{912.,0.0394},{912.8,0.},{913.6,0.2756},{914.4,0.4331},{915.2,0.2756},{916.,0.0787},{916.8,0.},{917.6,0.4724},{918.4,2.0472},{919.2,2.6378},{920.,2.6378},{920.8,2.3622},{921.6,2.2441},{922.4,1.9685},{923.2,2.0866},{924.,2.2441},{924.8,2.126},{925.6,1.6142},{926.4,1.1024},{927.2,0.9055},{928.,0.9055},{928.8,0.9843},{929.6,0.8268},{930.4,0.6299},{931.2,0.5906},{932.,0.5906},{932.8,0.5118},{933.6,0.5118},{934.4,0.5512},{935.2,0.5118},{936.,0.3543},{936.8,0.2362},{937.6,0.3937},{938.4,0.5118},{939.2,0.5512},{940.,0.4331},{940.8,0.4331},{941.6,0.2756},{942.4,0.1181},{943.2,0.1575},{944.,0.3937},{944.8,0.5118},{945.6,0.3543},{946.4,0.1575},{947.2,0.0394},{948.,0.0394},{948.8,0.1181},{949.6,0.1575},{950.4,0.2362},{951.2,0.2362},{952.,0.1969},{952.8,0.1575},{953.6,0.1575},{954.4,0.1969},{955.2,0.2362},{956.,0.1575},{956.8,0.1181},{957.6,0.1969},{958.4,0.2362},{959.2,0.2362},{960.,0.1969},{960.8,0.1969},{961.6,0.1181},{962.4,0.0394},{963.2,0.1181},{964.,0.1575},{964.8,0.1181},{965.6,0.1575},{966.4,0.1575},{967.2,0.1575},{968.,0.1181},{968.8,0.0787},{969.6,0.0787},{970.4,0.1181},{971.2,0.1575},{972.,0.1969},{972.8,0.1969},{973.6,0.1575},{974.4,0.0787},{975.2,0.},{976.,0.0394},{976.8,0.0787},{977.6,0.0787},{978.4,0.1181},{979.2,0.1181},{980.,0.0787},{980.8,0.0394},{981.6,0.},{982.4,0.0394},{983.2,0.0787},{984.,0.0787},{984.8,0.0787},{985.6,0.0394},{986.4,0.0394},{987.2,0.0787},{988.,0.1181},{988.8,0.0787},{989.6,0.1181},{990.4,0.0787},{991.2,0.0787},{992.,0.0787},{992.8,0.1181},{993.6,0.1575},{994.4,0.1181},{995.2,0.0394},{996.,0.0394},{996.8,0.0394},{997.6,0.0394},{998.4,0.1181},{999.2,0.1181},{1000.,0.1181},{1000.8,0.0787},{1001.6,0.0394},{1002.4,0.0787},{1003.2,0.0787},{1004.,0.0787},{1004.8,0.0394},{1005.6,0.0394},{1006.4,0.0787},{1007.2,0.1181},{1008.,0.1575},{1008.8,0.1181},{1009.6,0.0787},{1010.4,0.},{1011.2,-0.0787},{1012.,0.},{1012.8,0.0787},{1013.6,0.1181},{1014.4,0.0787},{1015.2,0.0787},{1016.,-0.0394},{1016.8,-0.0394},{1017.6,0.},{1018.4,0.},{1019.2,0.0787},{1020.,0.1181},{1020.8,0.0787},{1021.6,0.0394},{1022.4,0.0394},{1023.2,0.0787},{1024.,0.0394},{1024.8,0.0394},{1025.6,0.0394},{1026.4,0.0787},{1027.2,0.0394},{1028.,0.1181},{1028.8,0.1181},{1029.6,0.1181},{1030.4,0.0394},{1031.2,0.0787},{1032.,0.0394},{1032.8,0.},{1033.6,0.},{1034.4,0.0394},{1035.2,0.0787},{1036.,0.0394},{1036.8,0.0394},{1037.6,0.0394},{1038.4,0.},{1039.2,0.0394},{1040.,0.0787}}
```

Comment: try working with `NonlinearModelFit`, which has a provision to supply weights.

Comment: When I extract signalpart2 I get 200 components. You are using signalpart2[[1138 ;; 1400] in your call to FindFit. This is over 200 components. Can you share the exact data you are using. What are the manual parameters that fit the data better?

Comment: Using all 200 points the error I get between the manual values of 80, 915 and 8.5 is 10.26 while the error I get between the fit values using all 200 points and default parameters for FindFit (80.6, 910.1, 11.24) is indeed better (an error of 8.2).

Comment: Now I tried elements 38 to 90 to fit the data. I still get a smaller error using FindFit than the manual parameters. I think we need to know the indices of the data that you are trying to fit.

Comment: I understand the data should have a Landau distribution but clearly because the left tail does not drop to zero, it doesn't.  One wouldn't fit a line to something that is clearly quadratic, so why would one fit a distribution just doesn't fit the data?  But even then what you really have is a histogram - bins with counts (as opposed to x and y pairs where it would make sense to perform a regression).  Finally, why would a set of histogram counts get "capped" ?  Does that mean those counts are larger than 127 (which is the largest count that you have)?

Comment: To clarify/justify my claim that the raw data must be based on counts (or at least integer-valued readings), the predictor values are all separated by the same value (0.8) and dividing by the smallest non-zero dependent variable results in values are all close to ending in 0.0 or 0.5.  Multiplying by 2 then gets one all of the dependent variables as integers with the largest integer being 217 and the minimum non-zero values being 2.  Is the dependent variable a relative frequency or a multiple of a measure that is an integer? Trying to figure out how the data was generated to be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
george2079, I will look into NonLinearModelFit.

JackLaVigne, the original data is quite large (2500 components), do you still want me to post it? Or can I attach a file somehow? 

Jim Baldwin, I'm sorry, it seems that the axis labels have disappeared in the attached plots. It's voltage [V] plotted against time [ns] and it's the raw data from a sensor with incident particles, sampled by an oscilloscope. Due to a bug the range of the scope was too low, causing peak values to be capped. Ideally a Landau peak should be generated for a single particle,

Comment: but due to various reasons the generated signals don't agree, especially so for the low values (noise, overlap of signals, too slow charge collection etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fit various parts of the data you can use this Manipulate to set the start and stop indices (Note: In version 10.1 when you first open up the Manipulate variables to type in an index it will jump to a bad value. Just type in the good value and it will resurrect itself).

```
Manipulate[
 landfit = FindFit[signalpart2[[startIndex ;; stopIndex]],
   Landau[ampl, x0, sigma, x],
   {
    {ampl, 80},
    {x0, 915},
    {sigma, 8.5}
    },
   x
   ];
 Column[{
   landfit,
   Show[
    Plot[Landau[ampl, x0, sigma, x] /. landfit,
     {x, 880, 1060},
     PlotRange -> {{870, 1070}, {0, 3}},
     PlotStyle -> Red,
     AxesOrigin -> {870, 0}
      ],
    ListPlot[signalpart2],
    ListPlot[signalpart2[[startIndex ;; stopIndex]], PlotStyle -> Red],
    ImageSize -> 400
    ]
   }],
 {{startIndex, 38}, 1, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{stopIndex, 90}, 50, 200, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Here is one snapshot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice! (+1) To work around the `Manipulate` issue, you can use `Appearance -> {"Open", "Labeled"}`. If they start out open, they won't do any funny jumping any more. I am worried, though, that such selective fitting may be a bit too *ad hoc*: to me, it is a bit fishy to select only a portion of the data to run the fit.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, if you're going to choose the data points based on the fit that you want, why bother having the data at all? You could just write down the fit to begin with. But this could be a good tool to check which parts of the data are behaving as you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much! This will help a lot in qualitatively understanding how it works and where it goes wrong.

Comment: @MarboB, you're correct, it's a bit ad hoc, but not without reasoning. I know that the higher values are more true to the ideal Landau peak that should theoretically be produced. Of course I will have to analyze how reliable it will actually be in the end and I can easily see if and to what degree the results correspond with reality or not.